# Akt phosphorylation at Thr308 and Ser473

Tags: phosphorylation

I am studying Akt signaling pathway. I know that phosphorylation at both T308 and S473 is prerequisite for full activation of Akt but wonder if phosphorylation/de-phosphorylation of one of them is prerequisite for another. In other words,

1. wonder if phosphorylation at T308 is required for phosphorylation at S473 or vice versa, or they are phosphorylated independently.
2. wonder if de-phosphorylation at T308 is required for de-phosphorylation at S473 or vice versa, or they are de-phosphorylated independently (wonder if there is any order of de-phosphorylation by phosphatases such as PP2A between the two sites)

If there is such order, can anyone suggests me some references?